# How do I show icon when it is hovered?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want my icons to be hidden when the cursor is not on them, but when the cursor is on the icons, I want the icons to be shown to me.

Comment: `span { opacity: 0; }` and `span:hover { opacity: 1; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `opacity: 0;` and `opacity: 1;` when onhover

or use `display: none;` and `display: block;` when onhover